# Como puedo obtener un id de manera dinamica tras un .map()

Tags: javascript

Estoy consumiendo una API y la muestro por pantalla:

Código JS

```
const ui_user = document.querySelector("#uiUser")

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const users = await api()
    console.log(users)
    // ui_user.innerHTML = userItem(users)
    render_user(users)

})

const api = async () => {
    const users_load = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    return result = users_load.json()
 }


const userItem = users => users.map(user => `
    <p> 
        <strong> name: </strong>  ${user.name} - <strong> email: </strong> ${user.email} - 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="${user.id}"> Save </button> 
    </p>
`).join(' ')

const render_user = users => {
    const user_string = userItem(users)
    ui_user.innerHTML = user_string
}
```

Código HTML

```
<div class="container row mx-auto text-center">
        
    <h1 class="card-title"> hola mundo </h1>

    <div id="uiUser" class="my-5"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

todo me funciona perfectamente.

Ahora, lo que quiero es guardar un usuario, pero no sé cómo obtener un **id** o un usuario, ya que lo imprime dinámicamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

He buscado varias maneras y lo he intentado de muchas maneras. Sin embargo, no he podido lograrlo.

Comment: Muestra algo de lo que has intentado para que podamos corregirlo

Comment: Convendría que pongas alguna clase más al botón de guardado, porque las que tienes ahora (`class="btn btn-primary"`) son muy genéricas y es posible que haya más botones similares

Answer (score 0):

Jdavid, no sé dónde lo quieres poner/hacer, pero se trataría de añadir un trigger del click de los elementos recién creados.
Una opción sería añadir a tu función `render_user` lo siguiente:

```
const render_user = users => {
    const user_string = userItem(users)
    ui_user.innerHTML = user_string

    ////////////////////////////////// Código nuevo
    const botones = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary');
    for (i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
      botones[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var btn_actual = this;
        alert (btn_actual.id);
      });
    }        
    ////////////////////////////////// Fin del código nuevo
}
```

En cualquier caso, te repito la conveniencia de poner agluna clase más a los botones de guardado. Por ejemplo, podría ser algo como `class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-guardado"`. Y entonces, usar esas dos últimas clases en lugar de las que he utilizado desde tu código.